# Firestore - Prevent overwriting when document already exists while creating documents with custom ID

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

```js
this.collection()
      .doc<MyModel>(documentId)
      .set(data);
```

I want to create a document with custom document ID, so cannot use `add()` on the collection, but `set()` on the document works. The problem is `set()` overwrites if the document exists. I want to prevent that behavior, create the document if and only if the ID already doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent overwriting in code, consider using `update()`. Update will update the document with the data you give it, but won't create it if it doesn't exist.

Alternatively you can [use security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) to enforce this behavior on the server.

---

If you want to only allow creation of a document, and disallow updates and deletes use these rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // A write rule can be divided into create, update, and delete rules
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow create: if true;
      allow update: if false;
      allow delete: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `update()` will update the document when it exists, but I am trying to create a new document if and only if the ID doesn't exist.

Comment: In that case you can use security rules as I said in the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a method that creates a doc if it does not exist and updates it if it does, take a look at this approach: [Github comment](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1272#issuecomment-343759077)